# Can't build RStudio IDE with boost 1.56.0

Tags: r, boost, build, compiler-errors, rstudio

I have some problems with building RStudio IDE from the source after updating the 'boost' package to version 1.56.0.

I used following PKGBUILD for Arch Linux package manager: http://pastebin.com/r1mgj1h2

Build log with errors: http://pastebin.com/FjMdxEKA

Error messages:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Linking C static library librstudio-core-synctex.a
/build/rstudio-desktop-git/src/rstudio/src/cpp/core/Assert.cpp: In function 'void boost::assertion_failed(const char*, const char*, const char*, long int)':
/build/rstudio-desktop-git/src/rstudio/src/cpp/core/Assert.cpp:40:10: error: 'boost::core::log' has not been declared
core::log::logWarningMessage(msg, location);
^
/build/rstudio-desktop-git/src/rstudio/src/cpp/core/Assert.cpp: In function 'void boost::assertion_failed_msg(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, long int)':
/build/rstudio-desktop-git/src/rstudio/src/cpp/core/Assert.cpp:64:10: error: 'boost::core::log' has not been declared
core::log::logWarningMessage(message, location);
^
src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/Assert.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/Assert.cpp.o] Error 1
* DONE (manipulate)
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:178: recipe for target 'src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Note: I've built RStudio in the clean chroot described in [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DeveloperWiki:Building_in_a_Clean_Chroot) article.

I think that one of the possible solutions would be to install the `boost` package into separate instance with [this](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/dependencies/common/install-boost) script. 
However it seems very complicated.

Sure that there are a lot of more simple solutions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# specify that namespace core is in the global namespace and not
# relative to some other namespace (like its ::core not ::boost::core)
find . \( -name *.cpp -or -name *.hpp \) -exec sed \
        -e 's@<core::@< ::core::@g' -e 's@\([^:]\)core::@\1::core::@g' -i {} \;
```